# Switching to macOS from Windows/Linux

Tags: macos, windows, unix

I am switching to macOS by getting a new MacBook Pro in a few days. I have never used a Mac before.

Where can I look for short guide or video tutorials that teaches macOS to power users. I am a software engineer, know Windows very well, and Linux relatively well.

Most of the guides I found are targeted towards non-technical users.

Comment: Can you specify what exactly are you looking for as a power user? The question by itself is very broad. There are various areas of macOS (Automator, Scripting) that one may be interested in as a power user. You can find a lot of books via a simple web-search on macOS in general (for power users) or catering to a specific area.

Comment: When you say "I know Linux very well" do you mean the GUI as in how to navigate around or are you familiar with opening up a Terminal Window and executing commands?

Comment: As already mentioned in the other comments  the question as written is rather broad, even the term "power user" is depending on the specific topic you are experienced in. You've got some helpful links in the answer below, I propose you start with them and ask new questions focused to an issue/concept you are unclear about.

Comment: @nohillside that was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Nahum Great! Hope you‘ll enjoy your new Mac. Feel free to drop by any time with new questions if you need additional information.

Comment: Welcome to the club :). Apple's yearly developer conference, WWDC is just around the corner (it's opening today). I suggest you to tune in. For more information check https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you are new to Mac and macOS, it is recommended to browse through Apple's official guides. A couple of them are linked below. They cover a lot of advance features and helpful tips for power user:

1. [Welcome to macOS](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/welcome/mac)
2. [Meet your Mac](https://support.apple.com/explore/new-to-mac)

Since you are also a software developer, it is worth mentioning that [macOS is based on BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_version_history#Development_outside_Apple) and offers a robust UNIX platform. You can also find all the major developer tools build natively for macOS. Command-line experience from using Linux can be easily transferred over. macOS comes with all the major shells (bash, zsh, ksh, csh) preinstalled, and they are accessible via Terminal.app. Bash is the default login shell (just like most major Linux distributions).

[Homebrew](https://brew.sh), a community developed package manager is widely popular among software developers. It is recommended to have it installed for managing packages. Homebrew also lets one easily install UNIX tools that Apple either don't provide in the default install, or provide an outdated version of. It is comparable to `apt-get` in Linux.

[Homebrew Cask](https://caskroom.github.io), an extension of Homebrew project can be used to easily manage installation of GUI applications.

A very popular and detailed guide for software developers setting up a new Mac can be found here: [macOS Setup Guide](https://sourabhbajaj.com/mac-setup/)

[Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com) has had a tradition of doing a long form review of new macOS release every year. You can find it interesting as a potential power user, and can pick up a lot of new tricks. The review for **macOS 10.14 Mojave** (latest release of macOS as of this writing) can be found here: [macOS 10.14 Mojave: The Ars Technica review](https://arstechnica.com/features/2018/09/macos-10-14-mojave-the-ars-technica-review/)

Lastly, if you are looking to build software for use with any of the various Apple products, don't forget to check out the comprehensive [developer website](https://developer.apple.com/), which has tons of resources for developing software and hardware accessories for Apple platform.

Comment: Comprehensive and succinct +1 ...